# Facebook Marketing API PHP SDK - "Filtering field delivery_info is invalid"

Tags: php, sdk, report, facebook-marketing-api

I'm attempting to make a PHP-application that generates Facebook ad reports for a company, using the Facebook PHP Ads SDK. I'm following the Marketing API QuickStart that essentially generates code for you. I have all access I need to reach the company's ad account ID.
**(I'm not showing the token- and ID-variables, unless absolutely necessary. If so, tell me)**.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdsInsights;
use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;

$access_token;
$ad_account_id;
$app_secret;
$app_id;

$api = Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
$api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());

$fields = array(
    'frequency',
    'actions:link_click',
    'call_to_action_clicks',
    'actions:tab_view',
);
$params = array(
    'level' => 'adset',
    'filtering' => array(array('field' => 'delivery_info','operator' => 'IN','value' => array('inactive','active','limited','archived','permanently_deleted','completed','recently_completed','not_delivering','not_published','rejected','recently_rejected','rejected','pending_review','scheduled'))),
    'breakdowns' => array('place_page_id'),
    'time_range' => array('since' => '2017-09-20','until' => '2017-10-20'),
);
echo json_encode((new AdAccount($ad_account_id))->getInsights(
    $fields,
    $params
)->getResponse()->getContent(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

However, when running the code I get the error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException' with message
>   '(#100) Filtering field delivery_info is invalid.

I try switching around in *$fields* and *$params* with parameters found in the documentation, but it switches the blame on other ones as I do, even claiming that some of them don't even exist as alternatives.
I've checked several times in the documentation, it should work.

Does the problem lie elsewhere, is it the wrong kind of ad account ID?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try adset.delivery_info instead of just delivery_info. That should work. I learned the hard way, seems like you need to append the object level separated by period for filtering options.