# Facebook Marketing API get campaign info

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm using the code autogenerated by facebook to try and connect to the marketing API to get campaign stats. In doing so, I'm getting:

> Uncaught FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException: (#100) results, actions:like, video_play_actions:video_view, video_avg_time_watched_actions:video_view, unique_actions:link_click are not valid for fields param.

```
$fields = array(
  'results',
  'reach',
  'actions:like',
  'video_play_actions:video_view',
  'video_avg_time_watched_actions:video_view',
  'unique_actions:link_click',
);
var_dump($fields);
$params = array(
  'level' => 'campaign',               
  'filtering' => array(array('field' => 'campaign.delivery_info','operator' => 'IN','value' => array('active'))),
  'breakdowns' => array(),
  'time_range' => array('since' => '2017-05-19','until' => '2019-05-19'),
);
echo json_encode((new AdAccount($ad_account_id))->getInsights(
  $fields,
  $params
)->getResponse()->getContent(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Above I used campaign.delivery_info per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46824974/facebook-marketing-api-php-sdk-filtering-field-delivery-info-is-invalid#answer-47233191). I've also tried (per the auto-generated code):

```
'filtering' => array(array('field' => 'delivery_info','operator' => 'IN','value' => array('active')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are asking for old values field, try this:

```
$fields = array(
  'reach',
  'actions',
  'video_play_actions',
  'video_avg_time_watched_actions',
  'outbound_clicks',
);
```

Hope this help

NB: `results` field is not available

Comment: Thanks, seems they need to update their quickstart tool, and I need to do a better job of looking at their documentation ;)

Comment: Hi @froggomad, yes for sure. Could you share where you see this in their documentation?